# Fancybox ajax loading images slows chrome

Tags: jquery, performance, google-chrome, fancybox

So I am loading a list of images into a jQuery Fancybox (about 10 images, all under a couple of mbs) and it is bogging down the chrome browser to such an amount that it is unusable. Watching chrome in my process list shows that when it loads it jumps from about 165mb memory to over 250mb, and when I mouse over anything it can get as high as over 300mb. I'm not sure if this is a known issue with fancybox, or chrome, or what? I'm not sure if I can write a fiddle for this one. Any thoughts / comments are appreciated.

Fancybox: 1.3.4

jQuery:   1.8.3

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codephobia/zUWrb/

**Edit:**

I have included a Fiddle to show some of the css, html, and javascript used. It's all pretty basic. And the images html that is output looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-width="60" data-height="60" data-photo="6889639425_49a61a9559_b_photo.jpg" data-thumb="6889639425_49a61a9559_b_thumb.jpg">
        <img src="../photos/contacts/6889639425_49a61a9559_b_thumb.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt="6889639425_49a61a9559_b_thumb.jpg">
        <div class="photo-details clearfix">
            <a href="#" class="photo-delete" data-id="">Delete</a>
            <a href="../photos/contacts/6889639425_49a61a9559_b_photo.jpg" class="photo-view" target="_blank">View</a>
        </div>
        <div class="check-icon"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code its hard to say what could be causing this, I would suggest using the 'Profile' feature in Chrome browser developer console (Ctrl-Shift-I on Windows) to create a JavaScript CPU profile, this will show you which part of your JS code is eating up the CPU.

Comment: Okay so I tried creating a profile and open/closed the fancybox 3 times ... nothing really pops out at me, program is at 99.46% and most javascript is sitting at 0.02% or lower.

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Could one of your Chrome extensions be causing the problem?

Comment: I hadn't and it works perfectly in the latest Firefox of course. Disabled all extensions in Chrome and it is still happening. I'll test it in a couple other browsers, but at this point it looks like a bug report for Chrome Dev Team as some sort of memory hog issue.

Comment: I have sent a bug report to Google as it is working as expected in Safari, Firefox, and IE (shockingly). http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172274